# Is there a Java SQL parser that supports the korean language?

Tags: java, sql, parsing, character-encoding, multilingual

I have to parse SQL statements in Java. I'm trying to use [zql](http://zql.sourceforge.net/) and [gsp (general sql parser)](http://www.sqlparser.com/) but they don't support the Korean language, triggering lexical exceptions.

Example statement:

```sql
select * from test where name = '한글왜안됨'
```

Can anyone suggest a solution or an alternative parser?

Comment: I guess "Korean language" is a bit narrow. The parser probably generally needs to support non-ASCII ***encodings***.

Comment: Ensure that the javac compiler encoding is the same as the editor encoding. In an international environment UTF-8 would be a good choice. At least GSP should be able to handle UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the grammar part of [JSQLParser](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/). It's built with JavaCC so it should either handle all charsets or be very easily modified to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Recently the fork of JSqlParser at https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser switched to UTF-8 parsing. There is already a section for special german letters. You could add like this korean language for **identifiers**. **Quoted strings** should already work for you without any change.

```
String sql ="select * from test where name = '한글왜안됨'";
Select select = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
System.out.println(select.toString());
```

This code past my tests without any modifications using JSqlParser V0.8.8.